# Using loops in django templates, the way you use them in python

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Can I do something like this in the django templates ?:

```
firstList = ["foo", "bar"]
secondList = ["foo", "bar"]
for counter_one, _firstList in enumerate(firstList):
  for counter_two, _secondList in enumerate(secondList):
    if firstList[counter_one] == secondList[counter_two]:
      print(firstList[counter_one])
```

Because if I could that would be super awesome :D

Comment: Why don't you use `_firstList` instead of `firstList[counter_one]` (same for `_secondList`, `secondList[counter_two]`) ?

Comment: It's more for myself because I am used to for loops since yesterday ^^ I didn't want to confuse things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> t = Template('''
...     {% for first in firstList %}
...         {% for second in firstList %}
...             {% if first == second %}
...                 {{ first }}
...             {% endif %}
...         {% endfor %}
...     {% endfor %}
... ''')
>>> t.render(Context({'firstList': ['foo', 'bar'], 'secondList': ['foo', 'bar']}))
u'\n    \n        \n            \n                foo\n            \n        \n            \n        \n    \n        \n            \n        \n            \n                bar\n            \n        \n    \n'
>>> print(t.render(Context({'firstList': ['foo', 'bar'], 'secondList': ['foo', 'bar']})))


                foo



                bar
```

Use `fooloop.counter0` or `forloop.counter` if you need an index of inner loop. (0-based, 1-based). See [`for` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

BTW, the code does not need index because the code only print elemetn of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at **Custom template tags and filters**

[Link to official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Also **Django Book** also provides a tutorial for Advanced Templating.

[Link to Django Book - Advanced Templates](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter09.html)

Its very easy to create your own template filters. I hope this helps

Comment: I will have a look at it